# What's the best way to replicate on-premise postgres database to AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication

I want to replicate data from the On-Premise Postgres(9.6) Database(outside of AWS) to AWS RDS Postgres(9.6) Database. I have found out that there are some ways like AWS DMS or using postgres_fdw.

What are the best practices to achieve it and have the shortest delay?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup and why a delay would be a problem?

Comment: I would create a representative test database and try both options.